# twilio react native integration

Tags: api, react-native, twilio

I'm trying to create a react native app that allows the user to click a button and a call to their phone will be placed using the TWILIO API. I have it working from terminal by typing node make_call.js(name of file) but i want the user to be able to make the call when they want to by inputing their phone number and clicking a call button. Heres my code. the credentials are fake. Is this possible??

```
var accountSid = 'AC76d99966f35141f7c8585e31ed740480'
var authToken = '6470ce0905736f0f9da91456f088e97cc2'

var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);



client.calls.create({

url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/',

to: '7781234564',
from: '6042322056',

}, function(err, call) {
if(err) {

    console.log(err);

} else {

    console.log(call.sid);
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can actually build phone calling directly into your application using the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk).

There is already available to, built by the community, a [React Native wrapper for the Twilio Voice SDK](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks evan! I've tried following that demo, still a little confused on how to integrate it to my app. I'm not quite sure how to run the call function when i click the call button on my app. because the call function only works when i run it in terminal.

Comment: You don't want to be running that Node.js code within your application. The main reason for this is that this embeds your account SID and auth token within your app and that can be decompiled, stolen and used by a malicious attacker. You can either set that code up on a server and make requests to it from your app, or investigate making the call from within your app, like I suggest in this answer. Did you take a look at the Twilio Voice SDK?